# Loop that inserts hashes in a hash?

Tags: perl

If I have the following

```
my %big = ();
my %a = {x => 1, y => 1};
my %b = {z => 1};
```

and would like to end with `%a` and `%b` inside `%big` so I have

```
$VAR1 = {
          'b' => {
                   'x' => 1
                 },
          'a' => {
                   'y' => 1,
                   'x' => 1
                 }
        };
```

**Question**

How to write a loop at will insert many hashes like `%a` and `%b` into `%big`?

**Update**

Based on the answers I solved the problem with

```
for my $x (@{$c->{slaves}}) {
    $big{$x} = {xx::getFsList($x)};
}
```

Comment: Be very careful if you want to create the names `a` and `b` and etc for the hashes dynamically. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#How-can-I-use-a-variable-as-a-variable-name%3f and http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, you code has several problems.

1. Curly brackets introduce hash references, not hashes. Hashes are created from lists, so use parentheses:

   ```
   my %a = (x => 1, y => 1);
   my %b = (z => 1);
   ```
2. What you want might be possible if you used `our %a` and `our %b` instead of `my` and turned of `strict refs`. That's because symbolic reference works only for global variables:

   ```
   for my $hash_name (qw( a b )) {
       no strict 'refs';
       $big{$hash_name} = \%{$hash_name};
   }
   ```

   You probably don't need it, though, as you already know there are two hashes named `a` and `b`, so why to loop over their names at all? If you really really want to save some keystrokes, you can generate the code with string `eval`:

   ```
   for my $hash_name (qw( a b )) {
       eval "\$big{$hash_name} = \\%$hash_name";
   }
   ```

   I don't think is more readable than

   ```
   my %big = ( a => \%a,
               b => \%b,
             );
   ```

To create a hash of lists coming from a function, you can use

```
my $char = 'a';
while (my @list = func()) {
    $big{ $char++ } = { @list };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a loop,

```
my %a = (x => 1, y => 1);
my %b = (z => 1);

my %big = (a => \%a, b => \%b);
```

Comment: It is actually a function `getList()` that returns a hash of the type `%a` and `%b`, so that is why I need a loop I suppose. I don't know how many times `getList()` will be called and therefore output a hash which should go into `%big`.

Comment: @JasmineLognnes: What exactly does the function return? Just a list?

Comment: @JasmineLognnes so keys should be `a`, `b`, `c` and so on?

Comment: I did a bad simplification of the problem and also mixed up `()` and `{}` for hashes. Please see the updated OP, where I have posted what solved my problem.